# What’s the top-right robot on Wirdou’s “These aren't the droids we are looking for” shirt?

Tags: character-identification, robots

The artist Wirdou made this great tee shirt design where there are two storm troopers standing in front of a bunch of robots from movies and TV.  I can identify all of the robots but one.

[image: Wirdou's "These are not the droids we are looking for"]

([Image from wirdou.com](http://wirdou.com/2014/02/13/there-arent-the-droids-we-are-looking-for/))

**Who is the right most top robot?**  The one just above Marvin from Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy.

Comment: It kind of looks like it could be a robot from Hugh Jackman's instant classic Real Steel, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I am shocked, comma, shocked that neither Tom Servo, nor Crow T. Robot appear in this image!

Comment: @Lexible I am even more shocked that you forgot Cambot and Gypsy!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Oh I didn't forget Gypsy... just had lower expectations for what would be iconized. (I did forget cambot. :)

Comment: For some reason I feel like its from some video game.

Comment: @Lexible CamBot is the one taking the group photo.

Comment: I was glad for the red box help on identifying the bot in question since that Marvin version was not at all like the picture I had based on the British TV series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4P3pvKmbsg ... Go to 0:27

Comment: @DWin you have to thank Paul D. Waite for the red box.  I just posted the original image and he did an edit on the image.  I am quite familiar with the British TV series Marvin. He even has a cameo appearance in the new movie.  I feel the new Marvin is wonderful. The design of the new Marvin was based off a comment from Douglas Adams saying he wanted the robot design to be like an iPhone.  The British TV Marvin was created on a very limited budget.

Comment: Man! Where's the robot from _When the Earth Stood Still_

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### He look suspiciously like a Rock 'Em Sock 'Em Robot...note the extended fist above Bender's head.

[image]

It appears the OP may have found the source graphic for this painting as well.

[image]

Comment: Good catch - I bet that's it.

Comment: Looks more like a robot based on ancient Mayan art than Rock 'Em Sock 'Em Robots to me.

Comment: I think you may be right.  I am going to see if any other ideas come in.

Comment: The only reason I don't believe it is based in Mayan artwork is all of these robots are fairly famous (in the right circles) and I was immediately put in mind of the Rock Em, Sock Em robots as soon as I saw him due to my familiarity with the toy as a child. I could see those robots being considered definitive cultural assets for children who grew up in Western society with an interest in science fiction and robots, making them at least tangentially as much a part of this tapestry as any other robot (famed omissions, MST3K, for example) deserving a place.

Comment: @gnash117 I am persuaded by the original art addition by the RESE Robots art. :)

Comment: The version shown above of Rock'em Sock'em is the updated version of 2000.  If you look at the original version of 1965, for example  http://www.vectis.co.uk/Page/ViewLot.aspx?LotId=457936&Section=6304&Start=40 (click on "Larger image" to get a better view; this is the United Kingdom version which was called the "Raving Bonkers") the resemblance is even better.

Answer (score 21):

[Wirdou says it's Rock'em Sock'em Robots](https://twitter.com/Wirdou/status/561935899915997185)

[image: Twitter conversation between the answer poster, and the artists.]

Comment: I already accepted @Thaddeus' answer. Since Thaddeus was correct I can't change it.  I am glad to see we were correct.

Comment: @gnash117 not a problem.